# jquery dynamically loaded popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I'm trying to load up a webpage dynamically with links and are working fine just seems to be ignoring the popup role/rel.

my divs anything to do with this?

Can anyone help me out?

```js
$("#button").click(function() {

  var term = $('#term').val();

  var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
      tags: term,
      tagmode: "any",
      format: "json"
    })

    .done(function(data) {
      $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {


        $("#theLinks").append('<a href ="#photo' + item.media.m + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"> Open pop-up ' + (i + 1) + ' </a> <br> ');

        $("<img>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#thePopups").wrap('<div data-role="popup" id="photo' + item.media.m + '"></div>');


        if (i === 10) {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div id="theLinks">

</div>


<div id="thePopups">

</div>
```

Comment: Don't create popups. You should put in markup the stub for Your Popup, then You can dynamically update the content.

Comment: ...in case You are in trouble, here is a piece of code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44317832/4845566

Comment: deblocker thank you very much for your comments